# JVM Terminated while installing IBM Installation Manager

Tags: java, eclipse, centos7, ibm-installation-manager

I am trying to install IBM Installation Manager in a Cent OS 7 VM.
My Installation files are kept at `/opt/IM` directory
The command I issued is

```
./installc --launcher.ini silent-install.ini -log /opt/mylogfile.xml -acceptLicense
```

But the installation fails with the following error message

```
**JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/opt/IM//jre_7.0.8000.20141126_1221/jre/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xquickstart
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-jar /opt/IM/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1446.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-launcher /opt/IM/installc
-name Installc
--launcher.library /opt/IM/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64                                                                                                                     _1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /opt/IM/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1446.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1d8003
-toolId isilentInstall
-accessRights admin
-silent input @osgi.install.area/install.xml
-log /opt/mylogfile.xml
-acceptLicense
-vm /opt/IM//jre_7.0.8000.20141126_1221/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xquickstart
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-jar /opt/IM/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1446.jar**
```

My JDK version

```
Java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.2.el7_0-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Exit code 13 almost always means a mix of 32 and 64 bit Eclipse and Java (they must both be 32 bit or both 64). I don't know anything about the IBM code to say what is mismatched.

Comment: @greg-449 I have already mentioned in the post that the JAVA is 64 bit and the installation Manager is also 64 bit ( because it shows arch x86_64).Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: have u find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the shipped Java runtime has the executable bit? I had the same error and the architectures matched, the problem was the missing executable bit. It's important to apply this on the Java version shipped by IM, not the system wide Java! Your output seems from the system-wide Java, since its an OpenJDK where IM ships IBM JDK:

```
# ./im/jre_7.0.100025.20180517_1135/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr10fp25-20180430_01(SR10 FP25))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20180420_384915 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR10_20180420_1715_B384915
JIT  - r11_20180420_384915
GC   - R26_Java726_SR10_20180420_1715_B384915_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20010803_384915)
JCL - 20180427_01 based on Oracle jdk7u181-b09
```

The JVM path could be found in the `-vm` argument of the output. So in your case, try

```
/opt/IM/jre_7.0.8000.20141126_1221/jre/bin/java -version
```

If this doesn't work because of the missing executable bit, add it using `chmod`:

```
chmod +x /opt/IM/jre_7.0.8000.20141126_1221/jre/bin/java
```